# Running NUnit from code - how can I output results to the console?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, nunit

I am running NUnit tests using `RemoteTestRunner`. In the end, I get a `TestResult` object containing the results. The unit test project compiles as a console application.
The problem is, after running the tests, the output gets somehow redirected, and I can't print the results to the console.

Here's the code. It doesn't output *anything*, not even `"Open, sesame!"` (although it does run to the end - confirmed in the debugger).

Any suggestions?

Also, is there a built-in way to list the failed results, given the `TestResults` instance?

```
public static void Main()
{
    TestPackage testPackage = new TestPackage(AssemblyPath);
    RemoteTestRunner remoteTestRunner = new RemoteTestRunner();
    remoteTestRunner.Load(testPackage);
    TestResult testResult = remoteTestRunner.Run(null);

    Console.WriteLine(testResult.IsFailure);

    Console.WriteLine("Open, sesame!");

}
public static string AssemblyPath
{
    get
    {
        string codeBase = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;
        UriBuilder uri = new UriBuilder(codeBase);
        string path = Uri.UnescapeDataString(uri.Path);
        return path;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to store the current output stream of the Console before running the tests with

```
var currentOut = Console.Out;
```

Then setting it back once the run has been performed with

```
Console.SetOut(currentOut);
```

> *Also, is there a built-in way to list the failed results given the TestResults instance?*

I haven't been able to find any. However, the following piece of code should provide you with some help. It recursively introspects the composed `TestResult` structure and outputs the result of each test to the console.

```
static void OutputResult(TestResult result)
{
    if(result.HasResults)
    {
        foreach (var childResult in result.Results)
        {
            OutputResult((TestResult)childResult);
        }
        return;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}", result.FullName, result.ResultState);
}
```