# NUnit get results programmatically during run session

Tags: c#, nunit

again i am trying to do something and not sure if it is possible. i want to run my Nunit tests and after each test is run, i want to output the result to my ui. the ui is custom and is used by my test team to run and see test results. when i say it is used, it is not developed yet (fully) :) - bringing me to this question.

my code so far

```
TestPackage package = new TestPackage(path);
RemoteTestRunner remote = new RemoteTestRunner();
remote.Load(package);
TestResult result = remote.Run(new NullListener(), TestFilter.Empty, true, LoggingThreshold.All);

while (remote.Running)
{
    // want to capture results here
    if (result.HasResults)
        // i can never get here while test is running
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about dumping the results as XML into shared location. And then your UI can parse/pick up from that location

Also try  to use common XML schema so that you can easily serialize/deserialize back from XML to C# object and vice versa

We have done smth similar in the past and above scenario has worked quite well

Comment: i would like to do that, but i am not able to know how to get the results while tests are running

Comment: what kind of build server are u using to run the tests ? cruisecontrol/teamcity ?

Comment: i am not using either.. is it not possible using c#/nunit alone? if not, i can ask my team to give me one of those 2.

Comment: well you are using RemoteTestRunner which should be good enough. Look up the API of NUnit to parse the result. this might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8819803/runnin-nunit-from-code-how-to-output-results-to-console

Comment: thanks again for your response :). i tried the above but it also gives me the result after the tests are complete. also, i am not able to enumerate the test names. this is more complex than i thought :(

Comment: hate to admit it but i give up :(. i am not able to use this API very well. not sure how i will even enumerate nunit tests using the source. its a helpful tool but a very complex api to learn and work with.